# Android video lags when trying to connect to Mi Band

Tags: android, video, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rtsp

I have a simple application that plays the RTSP stream using the VXG Video Player and vibrating the Xiaomi Mi Band when some conditions on the server are changed.
It worked well but one time I forgot my mi band in the other room and this was a time to vibrate band and to play the video and I saw the horrible lags of the stream(3fps).
When it is time to play video if the band is not connected application tries to connect to it but the band is out of range and this process is slowing the video.

---

Connection to the device looks like this:
 `device.connectGatt(context, autoconnect, BluetoothIO.this);`

---

The main question is why the connection process affect the video and how to solve it

Comment: Which device and what OS version are you using. Note that Bluetooth LE (4.0) has a number of issues related to chipset, see this old report that one company found: https://atmosphere.anaren.com/wiki/Android_Issues_With_Bluetooth_Low_Energy

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have LG K-220 with Android  6.0.1 and htc 10 with linage os 14.1 the laging presnt on both phones but on htc the fps drops only 20-30%